# VBA "---" appears as a blank in drop down box in excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

I wanted a default option to appear as --- in the drop down menu for cell along with yes and no but it appeared as blank. I have scoured the web for the answer as to why this happens but I have not found anything. I am just curious as to why this happens.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: I am sorry if the title was misleading, while I am doing the project in VBA this problem was excel-side...I was just using the data validation menu to create a drop down menu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you have done something similar to the example below:

[image: Data Validation List Example]

You have done all you can to "force" data validation cells not to be blank.
Think of the following; You cannot be certain that the user will even click on that cell, so you cannot display an alert or error if they leave the cell blank (otherwise it would be continuous and relentless).

What you can do however is select the "---" option yourself before saving. That way when the user opens the form/spreadsheet/etc. by default, any cell that they do not select "yes/no" for, will contain the default value "---"

**EDIT**

Ahh I see,
Excel thinks that the three "subtract" symbols are to be taken literally.
if you try and enter --- into any other cell, you will get a "warning" of sorts asking you if you meant '---

Try this (an apostrophe):

[image: example2]

Comment: I really cannot use a range of cells to populate the list, but need to hard code the list, so the source looks like ---, yes, no and the --- shows up in the drop down menu but appears as blank in the cell when selected

Comment: @user3543709 I have added an edit onto the bottom of my answer to solve your problem